# stem() plot function (similar to MATLAB) for Julia + Winston

Tags: julia

I am using Winston library with Julia for plotting. What is the stem plot equivalent in Winston as in MATLAB?
(Note : Here winston is in the tag entries is different from Winston library of Julia.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure there is something built in, but this seems to get what you want

```
using Winston

x = randn(10)

function stemplot(x, args...)
    n = length(x)

    p = FramedPlot()
    add(p, Points(1:n, x, kind="filled circle"))
    map(i-> add(p,  Curve([i,i], [0,x[i]])), 1:n)
    add(p, Curve([1,n], [0,0]))

    p
end
stemplot(x)
```

Comment: This is what exactly I require.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a stem plot function in the Winston package. Here is the docs page: http://winston.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fun/stem.html

tl;dr:

```
stem(y[,spec::ASCIIString])
stem(x,y[,spec::ASCIIString])
```